# Perl match and print numbers

Tags: regex, perl

I want to write a script which will parse through a file pulling out all the EC numbers (enzyme classification codes) it can find and print out a list. The EC numbers look like this: EC 0.1.2.3 or EC6.7.8.9

My attempts so far have not been successful - right now it prints out the whole content of the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;

open (IN,"ec.txt") or die "Can't read words file: $!";
while (<IN>) {
    chomp;

    $_ =~ /EC?(\d+)\s*/g;
    print("$_ \n");
}
```

Comment: You do not allow spaces and dots.

Comment: Please add some sample inputs and expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You print `$_` (the whole line) regardless of whether the matching was successful or not.

Moreover, the regular expressions only matches digits after `EC` or `E`, you don't handle the dots. Using `/g` with a single match is weird, too - it's usually used in list context or in a while condition.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    print "$1.\n" while /EC?\s*([\d.]+)/g;
}

__DATA__
EC 0.1.2.3
EC6.7.8.9
EC 1.2.3 EC4.56.78
```

If the `C` isn't optional, remove the question mark.

Comment: I think `EC?` should be `EC`. Nothing the OP said suggested that the `C` was optional, and I imagine they were using `?` to match an optional space

Comment: The C is not optional. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Should you not use `if` instead of `while`, it won't make a difference to the output but it makes more sense.

Comment: @123 it makes a difference for the last line here.

Comment: @choroba oh yeah didn't notice that, thought it was one per line.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
$_ =~ /EC?(\d+)\s*/g;
print("$_ \n");
```

to

```
while (/EC\s*((\d+)([.]\d+)){3}/g) {
    print ($1\n);
}
```

The regex would allow for blank characters between EC and the numbers-dots-pattern, and then search for four number sequences separated by three dots. The while iterates over all matches and prints every match on a single line, without the "EC".

Answer (score -3):

Do not print `$_`. That's the whole line. Print `$1` instead. That's the match in the parens `()`.

Try `/EC\s*([0-9.]+)/`. `\d` is only numbers, not dots. You're searching for dots as well, so `[0-9.]+` will do the trick.